# Do I need to register as a sole trader with HMRC to open an Etsy shop? (UK)

Tags: taxes, income-tax, united-kingdom, self-employment

I'm very confused about this Hobby Business Tax thing.
I want to open an Etsy shop to start selling my photo prints online. I wouldn't be doing the printing, Whitewall would, but I would be selling my own photos.

Will I need to register as a sole trader? If so, will this affect the tax I pay on my full-time job too even if I don't sell many or even any in a month?
I am *very* unlikely to be earning more than £1000 a year from this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don’t need to register with HMRC if your total income from this business (not profit but income) is under £1,000 per year, since there are no pretty much no circumstances in which this could give rise to any tax liability. See [here](https://goselfemployed.co/hobby-business-tax-rules-uk-2018/) for more details.